# Labelling BarChart

Tags: plotting, labeling, charts

I have only used *Mathematica*'s `BarChart` and related functions only recently and it does seem as though *Mathematica* is extremely cumbersome when it comes to implementing certain labels of the charts.

My codes:

```
BarChart3D[{{65, 59}, {51, 62}, {39, 46}, {58, 32}, {38, 41}, {33, 
30}, {32, 7}}, 
ChartLabels -> {"Health info", "Online banking", 
   "Real estate listing", "Info on jobs", "Government services", 
   "Educational content", "Job application"}, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}]
```

I would like to associate each label with each pair of values. There are 7 labels and 7 pairs of values. However, for such a simple task,  *Mathematica* does a poor job in recognising so and I cannot even begin to imagine how should I modify the above code in a manner that fits my demand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
BarChart3D[{{65, 59}, {51, 62}, {39, 46}, {58, 32}, {38, 41}, {33, 
   30}, {32, 7}}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[#, Below] &@{"Health\ninfo", 
     "Online\nbanking", "Real\nestate\nlisting", "Info\non jobs", 
     "Government\nservices", "Educational\ncontent", 
     "Job\napplication"}, None}, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This isn't obvious how to label the data at first, but if you look in the right section of the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart3D.html), you'll find

> By default, labels are associated with columns of data:

and then it gives instructions on how to change this behavior.  Here's how I would style your plot

```
labels = {"Health info", "Online banking", "Real estate listing", 
   "Info on jobs", "Government services", "Educational content", 
   "Job application"};
data = {{65, 59}, {51, 62}, {39, 46}, {58, 32}, {38, 41}, {33, 
    30}, {32, 7}};
BarChart3D[data,
 ChartLabels -> {
   Placed[labels, Above]
   , None},
 BarSpacing -> {0, 1},
 LabelStyle -> 15]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]